# How to put data from CVS file into a dictionary to make a graph?

Tags: python, csv, graph

I have an issue working with CVS files.

I've been asked to read 2 CVS files and make a graph with said data.
`lineDefinition.csv` shows info as follows:

```
"station1","station2","line"
11,163,1
11,212,1
```

`stations.csv` shows info as follows:

```
"id","latitude","longitude","name","display_name","zone","total_lines","rail"
1,51.5028,-0.2801,"Acton Town","ActonTown",3,2,0
2,51.5143,-0.0755,"Aldgate",NULL,1,2,0
```

I want a dictionary in which I have: `{"station number": "station connection1", "station connection2", ... , "station connection"n"}`

**How can I use `while`/`for` cycles to grab ONLY the info I need and place it in the dictionary?**

`lineDefinition.csv` has data of all connections between stations, and `stations.csv` has the name of the stations.

I've tried to read and place the info in dictionaries in the next way using lists and the append function:

```
import csv
dictgrafo = []
dictestaciones = []
dictline = []

with open('lineDefinition.csv', newline='') as csvFile1:
    for line in csv.DictReader(csvFile1):
        dictgrafo.append(line)
        #print(dictgrafo)

print("---------Graph:---------")
print(dictgrafo)

#Stations
with open('stations.csv', newline='') as csvFile2:
    for line in csv.DictReader(csvFile2):
        dictestaciones.append(line)
        #print(dictgrafo)

print("---------stations:---------")
print(dictestaciones)
```

Comment: You aren't creating dictionaries, you're creating lists.  That's not bad, but it makes random access impossible.  You don't actually need the `stations.csv` file to create a graph of the station connections, but you will need an appropriate data structure to store the graph,

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the help! This is way better than using the lists!! I had no idea that i could use csv.DictReader in that way! I had made a couple attempts in a similar fashion. (Not really, just tried the append directly without declaring correctly the "if" statements) Once again: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create a graph of the stations.  Note that a line goes both ways, so you need to make two entries:

```
import csv
dictgrafo = {}

with open('lineDefinition.csv', newline='') as csvFile1:
    for line in csv.DictReader(csvFile1):
        s1 = int(line['station1'])
        s2 = int(line['station2'])
        if s1 not in dictgrafo:
            dictgrafo[s1] = []
        dictgrafo[s1].append(s2)
        if s2 not in dictgrafo:
            dictgrafo[s2] = []
        dictgrafo[s2].append(s1)
        
print("---------Graph:---------")
print(dictgrafo)
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py
---------Graph:---------
{11: [123, 22], 123: [11, 9], 22: [11], 33: [10], 10: [33], 9: [123, 16], 16: [9]}
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

Comment: What do you mean with "two entries", if all connections are declared in each station: That is already considered Bidirectional. Am i wrong? @Tim

Comment: It depends on the data.  If the data has both [11,12,1] and [12,11,1], then you don't need to make two entries.

Comment: I see, so if i have a {11:[123,22], [22,123]} then i do no longer need to make 2 entries? @TimRoberts

Comment: What I'm saying is, in the final result, if 12 is in 11's list, then you always want 11 in 12's list.  If you know both directions are in the input data, then you don't have to take the extra step I did.  If not, then you need both parts of the loop.

Comment: Oh, i see! I might be able to place everything in the same loop, a couple attempts more should be enough. Thank you very much for the help! @TimRoberts